# Static HTML templates for client UI?

Tags: templates, html

I'm looking to implement a fully functional HTML5 application with most of the client code pre-packaged in a bunch of html files. To this end, I'd like to have a templating engine that operates on the html to reuse headers, footers, nav bars &c.

What is the best static html templating engine? And by that, I mean that it has to start with input files and generate a set of html files. This is to provide things that Javascript templates couldn't, like including html fragments. I am currently looking at [ttree](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/tools/ttree.html). Is there a better one out there?

Comment: I was going to recommend ttree, and then I reached the penultimate line of the question. It is an excellent tool.

Comment: @David Dorward - Create an answer then. If it really is the best, I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should just use ttree.